# How can i Show values over the NVD3 historical bar?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to show the corresponding value over the NVD3 historical bar. I have tried the code in Discrete bars. But I couldn't show the values.

This is an example for DiscreteBar:

[image]

But I want the same for Historical Bar

Comment: can you show some demo?

Comment: Please read the edited question..

Comment: What do you mean by "Historical Bar"? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Christoher, Please visit the following link https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/historicalBar.js

Answer (score 1):

`historicalBarChart` has no `showValues(true)` method (unlike some other nvd3 chart types). So, you'll have to implement it yourself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932881/3790954) shows how to do this.