# How to correctly centre text element on all bars of a nvd3 bar chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I want to display the y-axis values of a nvd3 barchart on each individual bar. I can display the values, but I do not know how to set the height of the text element to be at the centre of each bar without hard coding the value. I use

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-bar")
```

to select each bar,but this does not have an height attribute ( as far as I can see). "discreteBar" has a height, but I cannot get in an d3.select()

I appreciate any help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.css"> 
  </script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.css" 
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" >
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [
  { "Class":"One", "Value":500000 },
  { "Class":"Two", "Value":200000},
  { "Class":"Three", "Value":37000},
  { "Class":"Four", "Value":35000},
    ];
 var nested_data = d3.nest()
 .key(function (d) {undefined; })
 .entries(data);
  nv.addGraph(function() {
var width = 600, height = 600
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
  .x(function (d) { return d.Class})
  .y(function (d) { return d.Value})
  .margin({ top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 175 })
  .tooltips(false)
  .showValues(false)
  .width(width)
  .height(height)
  .color(["#deebf7"])    
  .tooltipContent(function (key, x, y) {
                   return '<h3>' + x + '</h3>' +
                     '<p>'+ '£' + y  + '</p>'
            })

chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.0f'));

    d3.select('#chartContainer')
            .append("svg")
            .datum(nested_data)
            .transition().duration(1000)
            .call(chart);

d3.selectAll(".nv-bar")
.append("text")
.attr("x", chart.xAxis.rangeBand()/4)
.attr("y", 40)
.text(function (d) {
          return d.Value
            })
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
    });
 </script>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably easier to do this in plain D3 instead of using NVD3, see [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I agree with your point, but for my purposes I need to use NVD3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things make this work.

First, you can't write the labels until the transition is over since the `rects` won't have their proper height until then.

Second, you can get the rect height by using `previousSibling` of the text you just added.  Putting this together:

```
d3.select('#chartContainer')
    .append("svg")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .datum(nested_data)
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .call(chart)
    .each("end", function() {
      d3.selectAll(".nv-bar")
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", chart.xAxis.rangeBand() / 4)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return d3.select(this.previousSibling).attr('height') / 2;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.Value
        })
    });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vao08uONtDFjuMWkyWDc?p=preview).